# Why does sending an authenticated request immediately after logging in fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React [app](https://rgb-challenge-1988.netlify.app/) in which attaching an authorization header to my requests to an Express server, as seen in the code below. This should be straightforward, but for whatever reason it fails at first trial, immediately after logging in.

Specifically, when I open the app in the browser, log in and then navigate to a page in which an authorized request to the server is needed, said request fails. However, when I refresh the browser, that same request (and any other subsequent request) is successful. What gives?

My logging in process is pretty straightforward, with a successfully logged in guest being redirected to the home page.

**Axios Config**

```
import axios from 'axios';

function setAuthToken(token) {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '';

  delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];

  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
}

export function authRequest() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('some-token-name');

  setAuthToken(token);

  return {
    get: (path, options = {}) =>
      axios.get(path, options),
    post: (path, data, options = {}) =>
      axios.post(path, data, options),
    patch: (path, data, options = {}) =>
      axios.patch(path, data, options),
    delete: (path, options = {}) =>
      axios.delete(path, options),
  };
}
```

**Log in form**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { authRequest } from '../../../helpers';

import { AuthContext } from '../../../context';

import style from './index.module.scss';

const request = authRequest();

class LoginForm extends Component {
  static contextType = AuthContext;

  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    loading: false,
    errors: [],
  };

  onChange = (e) =>
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });

  onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    const { history } = this.props;
    const { handleAuthentication } = this.context;

    this.setState({
      loading: true,
      errors: [],
    });

    try {
      const {
        data: { token, user },
      } = await request.post('/auth/login', {
        username,
        password,
      });

      if (token && user) {
        handleAuthentication(true, user);

        localStorage.setItem('some-token-name', token);

        this.setState({
          username: '',
          password: '',
          loading: false,
          errors: [],
        });

        history.push('/');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({
        errors: [...this.state.errors, error.response.data],
        loading: false,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { username, password, loading, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <form className={style.form} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className={style['form-field']}>
          <label className={style.label}>Username</label>
          <input
            className={style.input}
            name="username"
            value={username}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={style['form-field']}>
          <label className={style.label}>Password</label>
          <input
            className={style.input}
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </div>
        {errors.length > 0 && (
          <ul className={style['error-messages']}>
            {errors.map((error, index) => (
              <li className={style['error-message']} key={index}>
                {error}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
        <div className={style['form-field-btn']}>
          <button className={style.button} type="submit">
            Log{loading && 'ging'} in{loading && '...'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

**Home Page**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import style from './index.module.scss';

function HomePage() {
    const { home, rules, link } = style;

  return (
    <div className={home}>
        <div className={rules}>
          <h2 className={style['rules-title']}>Game Information & Rules</h2>
          <ul className={style['rules-list']}>
            <li className={style['list-item']}>
              Difficulty levels: Easy, Medium, Hard, Expert.
            </li>
            <li className={style['list-item']}>
              Number of color boxes (circles) per difficulty level: 5 for Easy, 10 for
              Medium, 20 for Hard, and 25 for Expert.
            </li>
            <li className={style['list-item']}>
              Score for each correct guess per difficulty level: 1 for Easy, 2 for
              Medium, 3 for Hard, and 5 for Expert.
            </li>
            <li className={style['list-item']}>
              Number of tries for each round per difficulty level: 2 for Easy and Medium, and 3 for
              Hard and Expert. Tries reset after every correct guess while game ends after tries are over.
            </li>
            <li className={style['list-item']}>
              Click on color corresponding to generated RGB code to play.
            </li>
            <li className={style['list-item']}>Changing difficulty mid-game restarts game.</li>
            <li className={style['list-item']}>Most of all, enjoy!</li>
          </ul>
          <Link to="/game/play" className={link}>Play Game</Link>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Can you add code for Home page as well.

Comment: @MuhammadAli I'm not sure it's going to help as it is simply a stateless component with a list of instructions. Either way, you got it. I've edited the explanation to include a link to the app. You could try it out and see for yourself the issue I'm referring to.

Comment: @CollinsOrlando, I think this is because of the `synchronous behavior` of this language. Your tokens are not being set as you are expecting them to be.

Comment: @fahadtufail The auth token isn't attached to the header upon the first request after logging in. It does get attached after refreshing the tab/browser. It's bizarre since this is not the first time I'm using the same architecture. I've a couple of apps which work the same way and I experience no issues. So why this?